# Cost sensitive folds

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, fold

Let me explain what I mean by a cost-sensitive fold with an example: calculating pi with arbitrary precision.  We can use the [Leibniz formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_%CF%80) (not very efficient, but nice and simple) and lazy lists like this:

```
pi = foldr1 (+) [(fromIntegral $ 4*(-1)^i)/(fromIntegral $ 2*i+1) | i<-[0..]]
```

Now, obviously this computation will never complete because we must compute every value in the infinite list.  But in practice, I don't need the exact value of pi, I just need it to some specified number of decimal places.  I could define pi' like this:

```
pi' n = foldr1 (+) [(fromIntegral $ 4*(-1)^i)/(fromIntegral $ 2*i+1) | i<-[0..n]]
```

but it's not at all obvious what value for n I need to pass in to get the precision I want.  What I need is some sort of cost-sensitive fold, that will stop folding whenever I achieve the required accuracy.  Does such a fold exist?

(Note that in this case it is easy to see if we've achieved the required accuracy.  Because the Leibniz formula uses a sequence that alternates sign with each term, the error will always be less than the absolute value of the next term in the sequence.)

Edit: It would be really cool to have cost-sensitive folds that could also consider computation time/power consumption.  For example, I want the most accurate value of pi given that I have 1 hour of computation time and 10kW-hrs to spend.  But I realize this would no longer be strictly functional.

Comment: It's relatively easy to define such a fold yourself, but I assume you are asking if there is a built-in function with signature something like `(a -> b -> b) -> (b -> Bool) -> [a] -> b`.

Comment: @dbaupp Your function definition is not quite sufficient because `(b -> Bool)` only works for a very limited number of stopping conditions.  For example, if the sequence were not monotonically alternating, then the trick of only looking at the next number would not work.  In general, you may have to consider an arbitrary number of elements to determine if a sequence has sufficiently converged.

Comment: Of course. So a more useful type signature might be a function with `[b] -> Bool` rather than just `b -> Bool`? (One could implement something close with `scanl` and `dropWhile` or `foldr`.)

Comment: @dbaupp  This starts raising questions about the complexity of your stopping condition.  If the condition is too complex, checking it too often will drastically slow your computation.  But if you don't check often enough, then you may compute values that you don't need to.  So I guess my question is more about these theoretical aspects of cost-sensitive folding, and if anyone has studied them at all, rather than just being able to make a specific implementation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My recommendation is to use a scan instead of a fold.  Then traverse the resulting list, until you find the precision you want.  A useful special case of the left scan (`scanl`) is the `iterate` function:

```
piList :: [Double]
piList =
    map (4*) .
    scanl (+) 0 .
    map recip .
    iterate (\x -> -(x + 2 * signum x)) $ 1
```

You can now traverse this list.  For example you might check when the change to a certain precision becomes invisible:

```
findPrec :: (Num a, Ord a) => a -> [a] -> Maybe a
findPrec p (x0:x1:xs)
    | abs (x1 - x0) <= p = Just x0
    | otherwise          = findPrec p (x1:xs)
findPrec _ _ = Nothing
```

Answer (score 4):

The Haskell way to do this is to produce an infinite list of ever-more-accurate answers, then reach in and grab the one with the right accuracy.

```
import Data.List (findIndex)
pis = scanl (+) 0 [4*(-1)**i/(2*i+1) | i <- [0..]]
accuracies = zipWith (\x y -> abs (x-y)) pis (tail pis)
piToWithin epsilon = case findIndex (<epsilon) accuracies of
    Just n  -> pis !! n
    Nothing -> error "Wow, a non-terminating loop terminated!"
```

Answer (score 2):

In general case the fold you ask does not exist. You have to provide accuracy estimate yourself. It may be problem in general, but all practically useful sequences do have a reasonable upper estimate for numerical accuracy of partial sums, usually obtained by someone else. However, I should encourage you to read relevant textbooks, such as numerical analysis textbooks, that usually have part about estimating sum of infinite numerical sequence and giving upper estimate to it.

There is, however, a general rule, that if numerical process has limit, then numerical shifts come toward zero as rough geometrical progression, so if two subsequent shifts are 1.5 and 1.0, then the following shift would be somewhere about 0.6 and so on (it is better to accumulate such estimate over several last members list, not only 2 members). Using this rule and equation for sum of geometrical progression, you usually can find a reasonable estimate for numerical accuracy. Note: this is empirical rule (it has name, but I forgot it), not a strict theorem.

Additionally, representation of IEEE Double/Float has limited accuracy and at some point addition of small numbers from tail of sequence will not change computed partial sum. You are encouraged to read about floating point representation in x86 for this case, you may find your fold.

Summary: there is no solution in general, but usually there are reasonable estimates in practice for most useful sequences, usually obtained from literature for each sequence type or numerical limitations of hardware

Answer (score 1):

Some good examples of what [Daniel Wagner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/791604/daniel-wagner) suggests above may be found in the paper [Why Functional Programming Matters](http://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/people/staff/dat/miranda/whyfp90.pdf)

Specific examples from the paper are: iterative root-finding, numeric differentiation and numeric integration.

Comment: You mispellt Daniels first name. Unfortunately I cannot fix it myself as one-letter-edits are not allowed here.